# Jquery Accordion / Scrollto but need a Fade in and out?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fadein, fadeout, jquery-ui-accordion

I am a graphic designer but not the most web savvy when it comes to jquery! This is currently my dilemma; I have a series of links that I want to open in accordion and display images in sequential list where scroll to navigates to the link clicked and fades in and out as links are clicked, this is what I found that does this except the fading: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/6EWAF/

and heres a link showing the fade in and out I am after with the same accordion I just want to combine these two styles!
http://nekudacom.com/martimi/flash.html#

The link is the JSFiddle provided Dutchie432 if any one can help me implement both these two together or a better way about using putting together an accordion with scrollto and fading would be awesome!

Here is my HTML

```
<dt><a href="#"><h3><span class="redtext">/</span> yaya Photography</h3></a></dt>

<dd style="display: none; opacity: 0;" class="closed"> 

<ul>
   <li> <img src="images/yaya_spacing_white.png" alt="yaya_spacing_white" width="600" height="406" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yayaspacing_black.png" alt="yayaspacing_black" width="600" height="406" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_logo.png" alt="yaya_logo" width="601" height="401" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_typography.png" alt="yaya_typography" width="600" height="402" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_business_colors.png" alt="yaya_business_colors" width="600" height="403" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_buscab.png" alt="yaya_buscab" width="600" height="600" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_papers.png" alt="yaya_papers" width="600" height="400" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_usb.png" alt="yaya_usb" width="600" height="400" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_website.png" alt="yaya_website" width="600" height="359" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_website_home.png" alt="yaya_website_home" width="600" height="360" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_website_contact.png" alt="yaya_website_contact" width="600" height="360" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_website_gallery.png" alt="yaya_website_gallery" width="600" height="360" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yaya_shirts1.jpg" alt="yaya_shirts1" width="600" height="400" /></li>
    </ul>

</dd>
```

Here is the jquery script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("dd:not(dd.open)").hide();
    $("dt a").click(function(){
        if ($("dd:not:visible") .get()[0] !== $(this).parent().next().get()[0]) {           
            $("dd").fadeTo("fast", 0);
            $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown("def");
            $(this).parent().next().fadeTo("def", 1);
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: what does `accordion with scrollto and fading` mean ?? you want to scroll on click or more??

Comment: Hi @experimentX my desire is to have the scroll to effect as shown in the Jfiddle link above I have updated to show my HTML and script if this more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change: function(event, ui) { ...}` or `changestart: function(event, ui) { ...}`
to define what happens when you open the accordion. 
ui.newContent` is a jQuery object with the newly opened content element.
See full documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) (events tab)